# How to calculate maximum coverage of a matrix by tetris tiles?

Tags: c, tiles, tetris

I am building a recursive function that will be given a size of a matrix (Rows and Cols).

The function will print the first optimal cover it encountered.

What I am looking for is the a way to calculate what will the optimal cover be, numerically. meaning, how many blank spaces will be left. Meaning, I need the stop signal for my recursive function.

There are 4 defined shapes; they can not be turned, but can be placed as many times as I want (including 0). These are the shapes:

```
XX
X0

00X
XXX

0X0
XXX

0X
XX
X0
```

0 representing blank spaces.

Given a specific matrix size, how can I know what is the maximum coverage of that matrix?
As to the algorithm itself that will return the first optimal coverage, I think I will handle it myself.

I am writing in C but not looking for a source code - only an algorithm, preferably simple :)

BTW, no luck with trying to convert ALGORITHM X to match my problem.

Comment: "The function will print the first optimal cover it encountered" -- this means it only will print the first *full* grid, right? An entirely filled grid may not be possible, so how to know there is a better fill? (Other than continuing testing patterns.)

Comment: Maybe try to look at Set cover problem or Maximum coverage problem on Wikipedia. You can get pretty fast and almost-optimal approximation algorithm that is easy to implement (greedy). If you seek even more simple solution you may use extremely slow brute-force algorithm - this one runs like "Find some empty field and try to put some tile here; Call itself recursively until any tile can be placed". The third approach: This problem for tiles 2x1 and 1x2 can be solved using dynamic programming so maybe (I'm really not sure) you can modify it to fit your set of tiles.